# ImportError: No module named wsgi.simple_server

Tags: python, macos, pyramid, wsgi

I've followed the installation instructions for Pyramid:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/install.html

Then trying to run the hello world program:

```
../bin/python helloworld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wsgi.simple_server import make_server
```

Googling hasn't yielded answers possibly because I'm new to python.

Reading from here:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/firstapp.html#firstapp-chapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the link you provided, the name of the wsgi module is *wsgiref*, so line 1 should be:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
```